# Node Mongoose Estimate Validation Failed Error

Tags: node.js, mongodb, mongoose, schema

I am getting a return status of 500 from my Mongoose node service. The error is as follows:

"Estimate validation failed: disciplines: Cast to Array failed for value "[ { majorTasks: [],
    disciplineData:
     { disciplinename: 'test 1',
       disciplineunitname: 'hours',
       majortasklist: [Array],
       _id: '5c1422ffe0051d22accb56f6',
       __v: 0 },
    disciplineInstanceName: 'test',
    estimateEffortUnits: 45 } ]" at path "disciplines""

Code for estimate.js

```
const mongoose = require('mongoose');
const Schema = mongoose.Schema;
const { DisciplineInstanceSchema } = require('../models/disciplineinstance');
var ObjectId = require('mongoose').Types.ObjectId;


const estimateScheme = mongoose.Schema({
  estimatename: { type: String },
  summarytext: { type: String },
  scopetext: { type: String },
  disciplines:{type: [DisciplineInstanceSchema] }
});


module.exports = mongoose.model('Estimate', estimateScheme);
```

Code for disciplineinstance.js

```
const mongoose = require('mongoose');
const Schema = mongoose.Schema;
const { disciplineScheme } = require('./discipline');
const { majorTaskInstanceSchema } = require('./majortaskinstance');
var ObjectId = require('mongoose').Types.ObjectId;

const disciplineInstanceSchema = mongoose.Schema({
  disciplineData: {type: disciplineScheme },
  estimateEffortUnits: {type: Number, default: 0 },
  disciplineInstanceName: {type: String, default: ''},
  majorTasks: {type: [majorTaskInstanceSchema], default: [] }
});

module.exports.disciplineInstanceSchema = disciplineInstanceSchema;
module.exports.disciplineInstance = mongoose.model('disciplineInstance', disciplineInstanceSchema);
```

and discipline.js...

```
const mongoose = require('mongoose');
const Schema = mongoose.Schema;
var ObjectId = require('mongoose').Types.ObjectId;

const disciplineScheme = mongoose.Schema({
  disciplinename: { type: String, default: '' },
  disciplineunitname: { type: String, default: 'Hours'},
  majortasklist: {type: [mongoose.Schema.Types.ObjectId], ref: 'MajorTask' }
});

module.exports = mongoose.model('discipline', disciplineScheme);
module.exports.disciplineScheme = disciplineScheme;
```

I have checked the incoming data and believe it takes the right form to cast to this schema. I can't seem to find the issue with the cast.

[ { majorTasks: [],
    disciplineData:
     { disciplinename: 'test 1',
       disciplineunitname: 'hours',
       majortasklist: [Array],
       _id: '5c1422ffe0051d22accb56f6',
       __v: 0 },
    disciplineInstanceName: 'test',
    estimateEffortUnits: 45 } ]

There are no other errors being thrown for missing required files. I can't seem to figure out what is causing this error. MajorTask is currently not being generated but is not required.

Comment: Is that `disciplines` value a JSON string instead of an actual array?

Comment: JohnnyHK - That array is what was returned by the server as the error content and taken from Chrome dev tools.

Comment: That doesn't really answer my question :). Regardless, I think we're going to need a [MCVE] to be able to provide an answer this question (and the related question you also posted).